# How to Make Modification in Chutzpah Reports used Js Code Coverage

Tags: chutzpah

I am trying to use Chutzpah for Js Code Coverage.But now the problem is, i am getting the report in HTML Format but i need it in XML Format so in there any way to convert it.

Or is there any other Open Source toll or extension which i can use for Js Code Coverage Reports and to generate them in XML Format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chutzpah currently supports three format for coverage output which you can configure using the [Transform Setting](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/Transforms-Setting). There is the HTML, JSON and LCOV format. IF you would like another one I would be glad to accept a pull request for a new format as long as it is a standard one.

```
    { "Name": "coveragehtml", "Path": "coveragehtml.html" },
    { "Name": "coveragejson", "Path": "coveragejson.json" },
    { "Name": "lcov", "Path": "lcov.dat" }
```